# GCC Compiling error: expected specifier-qualifier-list

Tags: c, gcc

When compiling this code with gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>



typedef struct _Nodo
{
    unsigned int id_thread;
    int id_mutex;
    _Nodo *solicita;
    _Nodo *asignado;

}Nodo;
```

I get:

```
libdrm.c:13: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘_Nodo’
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try: `struct _Nodo *solicita`.

Comment: Also, note that this is not an issue in C++, but only in C. In C++ you can remove the (imho) horrible typedef and the need for _Nodo, and just write struct Nodo { ... };

Answer (score 2):

As Andrea has already said, it needs to be `struct _Nodo *` for both `solicita` and `asignado`, i.e.:

```
typedef struct _Nodo
{
    unsigned int id_thread;
    int id_mutex;
    struct _Nodo *solicita; // <<<
    struct _Nodo *asignado; // <<<
} Nodo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing a `typedef`, anyhow, do

```
typedef struct Nodo Nodo;

struct Nodo {
    unsigned int id_thread;
    int id_mutex;
    Nodo *solicita;
    Nodo *asignado;
};
```

i.e make a forward declaration of your `struct` and `typedef` in one go. The names for them need not be different. Then you may already use the `typedef` name inside the declaration of the `struct`.